# Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

Tags: drivers, php, mongodb, google-app-engine

I am creating REST APi with Lumen framework. I use Mongolab for my mongoDB and i want to host my app on google App Enginge. I am using Jessenger lib for communicating with my DB on MongoLab. Everhting is okay when I run the app localy but when I deploy on GAE I get

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~lumentestapi/v1.391053224987814328/ vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 56

I have enabled

> extension = mongo.so

in the `php.ini` located in root.

Any help how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the new **mongodb** driver rather than the **mongo** driver?

If so you should use:

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

in your `php.ini` file instead.

(I had that issue myself recently while upgrading our servers)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP7.*. with Ubuntu, you can do the following:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install php-mongodb`

This assumes you installed the library via `composer require mongodb/mongodb`

Then remember to restart your app's server. Check `phpinfo()` for `mongo`.

Comment: If it helps anyone else, only this has helped me solve the issue on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS nginx php8.0-fpm production server

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you init driver class as below

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost");
$collection = new MongoDB\Collection($manager, "logs","capped_logs");
```